# Create a pdf with just certain pages from a pdf

Tags: macos, pdf, formatting

I have a pdf, and I would like to select some pages from that pdf and build another pdf. Is it possible? If yes, how? I am on a El Captain.

Comment: The easy way hasn't changed in Preview for El Capitán In Thumbnail view select the pages you want, CMD-C (copy), File -> New from Clipboard (Save extracted pages to the new file). (See [How to Extract Pages from a PDF Document in Mac OS X Preview](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/extract-page-pdf-mac-os-x-preview/)).

Comment: Does not work for me: on Capitan 10.11, I don't have a "File->New from Clipboard" after copying page thumbnail.

Answer (score 3):

What you might want to try is this:

1. Duplicate the PDF you want to remove the pages from in the Finder
2. Open the duplicate file, show the sidebar
3. Select the page(s) you no longer want and press the backspace key
4. Once you have deleted the pages you no longer want, save the duplicated file.
5. If you like you can then open another PDF and drag the thumbnails from one sidebar to the sidebar of the other document, thereby adding pages from one PDF to another.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Does not work for me: I cannot delete pages in the sidebar (Capitan 10.11)

Comment: Odd, works fine for me. Maybe the PDF is protected with a password somehow?

Comment: nope, I tried with normal PDFs I generate, I can select a thumbnail but not delete it or copy it, are you also on 10.11?

Comment: Damn strange, yes I am. Sorry, no other ideas...

Answer (score 0):

There's a command-line option as well:

1. Install MacPorts (hosted by Apple) from https://www.macports.org/install.php . The link for your version of OS X, at the time of this writing, is https://distfiles.macports.org/MacPorts/MacPorts-2.3.4-10.11-ElCapitan.pkg
2. Once it's installed, run the following command:

   ```
   sudo port selfupdate && sudo port install qpdf
   ```

   Enter your password (it will not be displayed as you type) and push return.
3. Now, you'll be able to use the command `qpdf`. To do what you're trying to do, try this:

   ```
   qpdf --empty --pages ch01.pdf 1,5,9-15 ch02.pdf 1,5,7-20 -- output.pdf
   ```

   You can specify as many input PDFs as you want (in this case I'm using ch01.pdf, and ch02.pdf), the way I did here. Separate individual pages using commas, and page ranges using a dash, as I'm doing here. You can change "output.pdf" to whatever output file name you want.